# Laravel where condition issue

Tags: laravel, where-clause

This is my query string:

```
select `sku_alias`, `use_from_date`, `use_until_date` 
from `catalog_alias` 
where (`sku` = ? and `warehouses_id` = ?) and 
((date(`use_from_date`) <= NOW() and date(`use_until_date`) >= NOW() or `use_until_date` is null)) 
limit 1
```

generated from this code:

```
$whereCondition = [
    ['sku', '=', $sku],
    ['warehouses_id', '=', $wareHouseId]
];
$item = Alias::select('sku_alias', 'use_from_date','use_until_date')
    ->where($whereCondition)
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where(function($query_2){
            $query_2->whereDate('use_from_date', '<=', DB::raw('NOW()'))->whereDate('use_until_date', '>=', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            $query_2->orWhereNull('use_until_date');
        });
    })->first();
```

The result of  $item is `NULL`, my `$sku` value `'XXXXXXX'`, which is a string and I think my where condition is like 
`where (`sku`= XXXXXXX and ....` which it will end up in mysql error, because of the missing `''`.

How can I fix this issue ? How should I change this array: `['sku', '=', $sku],`  ?

Thank you

UPDATE: See mysql error:
[image]

If I use a direct query:

```
$item = DB::select("select
      `sku_alias`,
      `use_from_date`,
      `use_until_date`
    from `catalog_alias`
    where (`sku` = '{$sku}' and `warehouses_id` = '{$wareHouseId}') and
          ((date(`use_from_date`) <= NOW() and date(`use_until_date`) >= NOW() or `use_until_date` is null))
    limit 1;");
```

It works, just curious why the first type query doesn't work  ?

Comment: you THINK it ends up in a SQL-error? can you please verfiy this?

Comment: at this point , I am not sure . I need a coffee:)  See my screenshot .

Comment: It would be much more readable if you used separate where statements and avoided the $whereConditions array in my opinion.  Also, why do you have two levels of nesting in your last where statement?